# How to merge existing trigger code in managed package trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have installed one package in my org. when i write one trigger on campaignMember then it get in recursive call due to managed package trigger. Now i want to merge my code in package code. 
I want any suggetion how can i do that?

Comment: you can't see and edit your managed package code. One way is to get the code from github if it is available from there and edit it.

Comment: If i can't use their plugin and then merge my code in that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not able to change managed package code since that is managed by package provider. 
You can imagine that a compiled library that you are used, where you are aware only about available interfaces only, but no more.

You can do following things in here:

1. Ensure that your trigger is not recursive and as much safe as possible (so it does apply only necessary changes)
2. Contact provider of the package and explain your problem, so they can probably give you a hint how to avoid recursion

If that package is open source -- then you can (depending on license) get unmanaged version of it, and perform necessary adjustments.

**This is an addition to previously given answer.**

That is a first time that I have ever seen this package(fullcircleinsights) and their documentation.

I wrote some pseudocode based on their documentation, based on their documentation -- [link](https://support.fullcircleinsights.com/Full_Circle_Response_Management/Response_Management_Admin_Zone/Response_Management_SDK/40_Building_an_Extensibility_Plugin). 
(which is really good, one day I will start writing same I hope).

It should give you a way how to write it. Please, ensure that returned types are correct and data is being returned.
So, your class should have following methods (based on documentation [of interfaces](https://support.fullcircleinsights.com/Full_Circle_Response_Management/Response_Management_Admin_Zone/Response_Management_SDK/40_Building_an_Extensibility_Plugin/41_The_FCR_ExtensibilityAPI_Class_Interfaces_and_Methods)):

- ExtensibilityEvent
- GetUniqueName
- RequestedAPIs
- RequestedFields

The most important method is apparently **ExtensibilityEvent**. It may be executed in various places, for example in Trigger. 
In that case, PostSequence will be returned as eventname (according to event reference [in pdf](https://support.fullcircleinsights.com/@api/deki/pages/931/pdf/Extensibility%2BEvents%2BReference.pdf))

Here is an example plugin.

```
global class SamplePlugin Implements FCRM.FCR_ExtensibilityAPI.IExtensibilityPlugin {
    global void ExtensibilityEvent(String eventname, FCRM.FCR_ExtensibilityAPI.IExtensibilityEventArgs args) {
        if (eventname = 'PostSequence') {
            // Returns 2 maps (or less) based on trigger event
            List<Object> data = this.getRecordMaps();
            // returns params, according to PDF link above
            List<Object> params = this.getAdditionalParams();
            //so if it is campaign member, and event is before/update, page 6 of PDF file
            if ((String)params.get(0) == 'CampaignMember' && (Boolean)params.get(3) == true && (Boolean)params.get(5) == true) {
                // do some dirty job
                Map<Id, Object> new_map = ( Map<Id, Object>)data.get(1);
                for(Object cm : new_map.values() ) {
                    CampaignMember cm_parsed  = (CampaignMember)cm;
                    //Change it in way that you want
                }
            }
        }
    }
    global String GetUniqueName() {
        return('SamplePluginName');
    }
    global SET<String> RequestedAPIs() {
        //no clue so far
        return new Set<String>();
    }
    global Map<String,Set<String>> RequestedFields() {
        return null;// no impact in trigger
    }
}
```

In the end, do not forget write tests (they have guide too) and to register you plugin by calling as anonymous apex following:

```
FCRM.FCR_ExtensibilityAPI.InstallPluginClass('SamplePlugin');
```

Comment: if i can't use their interface and use extensibility plugin for this?

Comment: If they provide such an interface -- then you can do it. (personally I did that for some of managed packages).

Comment: in their docs i read that there is interface which i can use. Can you please help me how you do that so i can take a reference from their.

Comment: @SalesforceFolks please, share package name, and documentation for it. I have no idea what package are you talking about

Comment: Package name is Full_Circle_Response_Management in which after searching i found there is 'Post Sequence Trigger' this we can use. But i not getting how i can do this.please share your answers.https://support.fullcircleinsights.com/Full_Circle_Response_Management/Response_Management_Admin_Zone/Response_Management_SDK/40_Building_an_Extensibility_Plugin/43_Extensibility_Events_Reference

Comment: is there any update on this, as i still not getting how we can use this.Till now i get to know that i need to determine the sobjectType with ID.getSobjectType method and then on the basis of that need to call our code and paste that there.

Comment: @SalesforceFolks please, check extended version of an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the managed package code. For this you can contact the package provider and tell the scenario to them.